# How to bypass the 0-255 range limit for sys.exit() in python?

Tags: python, linux, exit-code

In python (on a Linux system), I'm launching a command using `os.system()` and retrieving the return code. If that return code is different from 0, I would like to make the program exit with that same return code. So I wrote:

```
ret = os.system(cmd)
if ret != 0:
   print "exit with status %s" % ret
   sys.exit(ret)
```

When the return code is lower than 256, it works fine, but when it's greater than 255, the exit code used is 0. How can I make sys.exit() accept codes greater than 255?

Edit: the limit is actually 255

In fact, the `ret` variable receives 256, but `sys.exit()` fails to use it, so the program returns 0 instead. When I launch `cmd` manually, I see that it returns 1, not 256.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Works for me (CentOS 5.5, Python 2.6.5):

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exit(245)
$ echo $?
245
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the limit is 255, not 127.

Comment: The 255 limit is enforced by the shell: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html and http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.wait) indicates that

> exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process, and whose high byte is the exit status (if the signal number is zero); the high bit of the low byte is set if a core file was produced.

So I need to process the number returned by sys.exit() in order to retrieve the real exit status, like so:

```
ret = os.system(cmd)
# Ignore the first byte, use the second one only
ret = ret >> 8
if ret != 0:
   print "exit with status %s" % ret
   sys.exit(ret)
```

And now it works: ret contains 1 instead of 256.

Comment: Oh. I just started to wonder why it returns 0x8b00 on segfaulty termination.

Comment: I think if it dumps core that will give you a different exit code to what you would have got if you ran it from the command line.

Comment: you could use `subprocess.call` instead of `os.system`: compare `python -c 'import os; print [os.system(["./exit-with", str(i)]) for i in [127,128,255,256,257]]'` and `python -c 'import subprocess
print [subprocess.call(["./exit-with", str(i)]) for i in [127,128,255,256,257]]'` where `exit-with` is http://ideone.com/zFelC

Answer (score 3):

You <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't, because the system reserves exit codes above 128 for itself. If the return code is from 0 to 127, it means that the program exited by itself. If the return code is higher than 128, it means that the program was terminated by a system signal (e.g. SIGKILL or SIGTERM). The signal number is the result code minus 128.

You'll need to detect it and make some other kind of output indication, I think. Perhaps print the return code to STDOUT and then return with either 0 (normal exit, normal output) or 1 (cmd had a non-zero return value, output means something).

edit: Apparently (from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448339/how-to-bypass-the-0-127-range-limit-for-sys-exit-in-python/4448521#4448521)), Python is more clever than a shell script... To put it back into a regular Linux exit code, try this:

```
subprocess_exit_code = (ret >> 8) & 0x7f
subprocess_signal_number = ret & 0xff

if subpprocess_signal_number == 0:
  exit_code = subprocess_exit_code
else:
  exit_code = 128 + subprocess_signal_number
```

Although this ignores the core-dump information.