# python wrong subprocess.call return code

Tags: python

Look at this 2 simples programs in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return -1;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 1337;
}
```

Now look this very basic python script:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> r=subprocess.call(['./a.out'])
```

I do not understand why but the python script r value contains:

- 255 for the first C program. It should be -1
- 57 for the second C program. It should be 1337

Have i something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: return codes are a single unsigned byte `-1 == 255 unsigned byte` ... `1337&255= 57`

Comment: return codes range from 0 to 255 / 128 (system dependent): 1337 % 256 => 57

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448339/how-to-bypass-the-0-255-range-limit-for-sys-exit-in-python

Comment: cross site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/why-do-i-get-error-255-when-returning-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has nothing to do with it. This is system dependent.

On Unix/Linux systems, the return code is stored on 1 byte, and is unsigned, so truncation occurs outside 0-255 range.

So -1 becomes 255, 1337 becomes 57 (can be checked by applying modulus 256).

note that in Windows, return codes *can* be higher than 255 (was able to pass `100000000`, but still not negative)

The conclusion is: don't rely on return codes too much to pass information. Print something on the console instead.

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37915/why-do-i-get-error-255-when-returning-1